# (1) table Table_name has no column named Column_name

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I insert the record by using following code.But I get the error mentioned above as in title.For some time it will work fine but often it will shows the error like this.My code is,

```
    String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FROM + " TEXT," + KEY_TO + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BODY + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
```

Here I have called the method as,

```
 dbHandler.Add_Message(new Message(fromno,tonum,bodyy,datt,stt));
```

And this is my Add_Message method,

```
public void Add_Message(Message contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FROM, contact.getmsgfrom()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_TO, contact.getto()); // Contact Phone
    values.put(KEY_BODY, contact.getmsg()); 
    values.put(KEY_DATE, contact.getdate());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, contact.getstatus());// Contact Email
    db.insert(TABLE_MESSAGES, null, values);
    db.close(); 
    }
```

And this is the code for getting particular column,

```
    public int calculateunread(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String unreadquery="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " 
            + TABLE_MESSAGES + " WHERE " + KEY_STATUS + "='0'";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(unreadquery, null);

    int a=cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

            return a;
}
```

But I can't  insert my records, what  mistake I made here?

Comment: Is the error message exactly like the title, or there are some specific value instead of Table_name and Column_name?

Comment: Leading space to separate table name from column parameters: `String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGES + " ("`